# Generate files directly in HDFS

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

Is there a way to generate a file on HDFS directly?
I want to avoid generating a local file and then over hdfs command line like:
`hdfs dfs -put - "file_name.csv"` to copy to HDFS.

Or is there any python library?

Comment: You have to use `hdfs put` because that's how HDFS blocks are made. You can `touch` an empty file in a recent version of the Hadoop CLI tools, but I don't think that's what you want

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with [HdfsCli](http://hdfscli.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html)?

To quote the paragraph [Reading and Writing files](http://hdfscli.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#reading-and-writing-files):

```
# Loading a file in memory.
with client.read('features') as reader:
  features = reader.read()

# Directly deserializing a JSON object.
  with client.read('model.json', encoding='utf-8') as reader:
    from json import load
    model = load(reader)
```

Comment: Thank you for you answers. For me is important that the file is directly genertate in a hdfs folder. 

your example there is a reader too. i need a possibilty just write functionality.

Comment: You are welcome! However, I was just posting the link to the documentation. If you tell us what is not clear, maybe by posting the code you have written so far, we might be able to help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Is extremly slow when I use hdfscli the write method?
Is there an any way to speedup with using hdfscli?

```
with client.write(conf.hdfs_location+'/'+ conf.filename, encoding='utf-8', buffersize=10000000) as f:
writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=conf.separator)
for i in tqdm(10000000000):
    row = [column.get_value() for column in conf.columns]
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Thanks lot.

Answer (score 0):

`hdfs dfs -put` does not require yo to create a file on local. Also, no need of creating a zero byte file on hdfs (`touchz`) and append to it (`appendToFile`). You can directly write a file on hdfs as:

```
hadoop fs -put - /user/myuser/testfile
```

Hit enter. On the command prompt, enter the text you want to put in the file. Once you are finished, say `Ctrl+D`.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways of write local files to hdfs using python:

One way is using hdfs python package:

**Code snippet:**

```
from hdfs import InsecureClient
hdfsclient = InsecureClient('http://localhost:50070', user='madhuc')
hdfspath="/user/madhuc/hdfswritedata/"
localpath="/home/madhuc/sample.csv"
hdfsclient.upload(hdfspath, localpath)
```

Outputlocation:**'/user/madhuc/hdfswritedata/sample.csv'**

Otherway is subprocess python package using PIPE

**Code Sbippet:**

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen    
# put file into hdfs
put = Popen(["hadoop", "fs", "-put", localpath, hdfspath], stdin=PIPE, bufsize=-1)
put.communicate()    
print("File Saved Successfully")
```